# guardar en base de datos múltiples archivos

Tags: html, fileupload

hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar si me guarda los archivos en mi carpeta pero no se como podria hacerle para que me los guarde en una base de datos espero me puedan ayudar en esto saludos

**vista**
en esta parte cargo mi vista

```
      <form name="MiForm" id="MiForm" method="post" action="cargar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h4 class="text-center">Cargar Múltiple Archivos</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Archivos</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="miarchivo[]" name="miarchivo[]" multiple="">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cargar Multiple</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**controlador**

```
<?php
foreach($_FILES["miarchivo"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
{
    //condicional si el fuchero existe
    if($_FILES["miarchivo"]["name"][$key]) {
        // Nombres de archivos de temporales
        $archivonombre = $_FILES["miarchivo"]["name"][$key]; 
        $fuente = $_FILES["miarchivo"]["tmp_name"][$key]; 
        
        $carpeta = 'archivos/'; //Declaramos el nombre de la carpeta que guardara los archivos
        
        if(!file_exists($carpeta)){
            mkdir($carpeta, 0777) or die("Hubo un error al crear el directorio de almacenamiento"); 
        }
        
        $dir=opendir($carpeta);
        $target_path = $carpeta.'/'.$archivonombre; //indicamos la ruta de destino de los archivos
        

        if(move_uploaded_file($fuente, $target_path)) { 
            echo "Los archivos $archivonombre se han cargado de forma correcta.<br>";
            } else {    
            echo "Se ha producido un error, por favor revise los archivos e intentelo de nuevo.<br>";
        }
        closedir($dir); //Cerramos la conexion con la carpeta destino
    }
}
?>
```

[ejemplo1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200832/como-subir-multiples-archivos-con-este-codigo)

Comment: Guardar los archivos subidos en una base de datos normalmente no es demasiada buena idea.  Aún así, si lo quieres, supongo que debes definir un campo BLOB en la tabla para guardar el contenido del archivo y mediante `file_get_contents()` puedes abrir el archivo que acabas de subir y guardarlo en la tabla de la base de datos.

Comment: que me recomiendas las guardo en una carpta pero quria guardar el nombre de la imagen en mi base de datos para poder sustituirla